# jQuery accordion plugin won't work once used in WP

Tags: jquery

I'm tryin to use this accordion script in my WP: http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/

Problem is that on a standalone html/php file it works well but once pasted in my header.php file there's no way to make it work.
I tried also including it with `<?php require_once("example.php") ?>` but no success.

You can see my header.php file here: http://pastebin.com/SrkmWxp1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: also, the example page here: http://pastebin.com/yEdnTPW4

Comment: looks like its working..

Comment: i assure you it's not working...i display all the static picture columned instead of the accordion as per the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to still be having issues, what i'd do to avoid having all that code clutter the header is setup a bunch of enqueues, but handle the html5 js inside the print scripts action along with the appropriate conditional comments(there's no proper way to do this with the enqueue system).

First the HTML5 js, outright just print the conditional logic and script tag(it's an appropriate action for this kind of thing).

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'do_print_html5js' );

function do_print_html5js() {
    echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>' . "\n";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/html5.js"></script>' . "\n";
    echo '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
}
```

**Notes:** Although to be honest, the above part isn't necessary at all and you could leave it in the header file, the TwentyThirteen theme just does that, i'd just personally avoid the extra clutter.

Then fire off your enqueues for the accordian, using the dependencies parameter to indicate to each script what other script or scripts it depends upon. I referenced the internal jQuery to, there's no need to fetch that externally.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_and_enqueue_scripts' );

function register_and_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jquery'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-zaccordian', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.zaccordion.js', array( 'jquery-easing'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-zaccordian', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myaccordion.js', array('jquery-zaccordian'), false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slidemenucss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slidemenu.css', array(), false );
}
```

Move your jQuery code that creates the accordian into a seperate file, and adjust the file name in the above enqueue, `myaccordion.js` as needed.

I tested the above code before posting this answer, here's the test HTML code i plonked in my **header.php** file and the jQuery used to create the accordian.

**header.php** - html (just the important bit)

```
<ol id="example1">
    <li><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="" /></li>
</ol>
```

**myaccordion.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#example1").zAccordion({
        easing: "easeOutBounce",
        height: "150px",
        slideWidth: "600px",
        width: "900px"
    });
});
```

Hope that helps and keeps your header file a little cleaner.. ;)

Comment: hi, thanks! your solution for sure makes my header cleaner!! unfortunatly the issue remains: the images gets loaded in a row and then after a couple of seconds they move into the accordition...

Comment: Maybe that's because you don't have the accompanying CSS the author is using to offset the accordion until it's loaded, the author has used additional CSS on his own site but doesn't include any with the download. Here's a [temp pastebin](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2362492) of his stylesheet but unminified, just pick out what you need from it(ie. the accordion stuff).

Comment: i took a look at those lines but they're really too much...
you can have a preview of the website here if you don't mind taking a look at it http://is.gd/FsEAV7
try also with different browsers

Comment: Looks fine to me.. FF, IE, Chrome and Opera. Maybe you have something in cache that's causing an issue?

Comment: i tried again now and it's showing correctly...but in local all the browser shows the issue...this is strange!!

Comment: Help me help you, what differs between the two??

Comment: don't worry...it might be a problem of the local apache server...the important is that on the outside server it works correctly. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code again. Here is what i think

**Change This:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.zaccordion.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                $("#example11").zAccordion({
                                        easing: "easeOutBounce",
                                        height: "150px",
                                        slideWidth: "600px",
                                        width: "900px"
                                });
                        });
                </script>
```

**To This:**

Assuming you have the accordion script on your theme directory. You can't use relative url inside wordpress. You have to use full URL.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.zaccordion.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // using jQuery instead of $ and passing $
                                $("#example11").zAccordion({
                                        easing: "easeOutBounce",
                                        height: "150px",
                                        slideWidth: "600px",
                                        width: "900px"
                                });
                        });
                </script>
```

**Doing It Right:**

Code I show is just how to get it working. You shouldn't add scripts on header at all. Use [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script). Then enqueue it using [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). All script should be loaded into footer area.

**More On How to Use jQuery with Wordpress**

http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: of course i wasn't using relative URLs but <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?> in the header.php (as you can see in pastebin link). the relative URL is only in the original script file. i will try add the jQuery in the way you suggested and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: You should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in the example, else the example fails in the case of a child theme. It would also be nice and i'd consider the answer better if it provided an example of loading scripts the WP way.

Comment: i tried using the script in the link you posted into the functions.php but it didn't work so i put the call directly in the header even if it's not the correct way to do it.
the script is not loading correctly: i get the images columned for a couple of seconds and then they automatically goes in their place in the accordion...is this because of a delay in the load of the script?

Comment: yes.. looks like it. how much is the script size?

Comment: @Sisir jquery.zaccordion.min.js is 12kb and jquery.zaccordion.js is 22kb but the same happens with another script i found that is only 1kb so i don't think it's a problem of heavy weight of the script

Comment: can you upload the site in the web? Can't help much unless i can see it myself.

Comment: @Sirsir use this link: http://is.gd/FsEAV7
try also different browsers

Comment: @l736k: okey, its for the late loading of the script. You can add a height to the accordion container and set overflow hidden so it doesn't look ugly when its loading.